# Flash drive to store Eclipse, ADT, Android SDK and projects

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, drive

I'm on a hunt for a flash drive to store Eclipse with ADT, the Android SDK and a few projects to bring to school, since their computers dont allow me to install Eclipse. I want it to support USB 3.0 and to have 8GB-16GB of memory.
Since I'm not an expert on flash drives and their read and write speeds, I thought I could ask for some help here!

So, since I'm going to run Eclipse and all that on it I assume it need to have quite high read and write speeds.

Anyone out there who knows a flash drive that would fit perfectly for my needs and wont bring a poor college student into bankruptcy? 
And yes, my laptop and my schools computers support USB 3.0.

Comment: "And yes, my laptop..." IMO you should skip the drive and just develop on your laptop if you have one. Doing all of your work on a thumb drive like this is asking for the disappointment of losing all of your work (misplacing, dead drive, broken etc...) If you are deadset on using a thumb drive I assume that faster would be better. But I imagine this question is somewhat to broad for SO. If anything it probably belongs on SuperUser, but I am not certain that shopping advice is on topic there either.

Comment: Although u cannot install eclipse you may be able to save a portable version in your "My Documents"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my favorite one at the momemt. Decent price and have had no problems.

http://www.corsair.com/usb-drive/flash-voyager-usb-drives/flash-voyager-usb-3-16gb-usb-flashdrive-cmfvy3s.html

Comment: Thanks! And yep, at least a few of them. The more powerfull ones that I use for programming. :)

Comment: @user1258829 Probably have a new building before my department upgrades,very sad situation. They bout new machines with 512MB ram